# What is the URL to a heroku git repository?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I am new to Heroku. Recently I created a NodeJS application with the Heroku git and deployed it on Heroku. I used the following command to clone the repository to my local computer from the Heroku git.

```
heroku git:clone -a {app_name}
```

How would I be able to browse the repository on the Heroku git rather than locally, like GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How would I be able to browse the repository on the Heroku git rather than locally, like GitHub?

You don't.

Heroku is a [platform as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) hosting provider, not a repository host. [You *can* clone from it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app), but that's not what it's designed to do:

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.

It doesn't provide a web interface to its Git repositories.

Comment: If I store my code in GitHub and push any changes to the GitHub repository, are they automatically pushed to the Heroku Git git repository?

Comment: @alextc, not by default. But you [can configure automatic deployments to Heroku when you push to GitHub](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys).

Comment: is automatic deployment configured on GitHub?

Comment: As the documentation I linked to in my previous comment says, this is done on Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

In your heroku account, go to your app -> Settings. 
Under App Information, you'll find the heroku git url.